# Use TYPO3 locallang.xml files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, localization, typo3

Is there a built-in mechanism to load the locallang.xml extension files to use the labels from JavaScript in TYPO3?

If so, what is the syntax?

I'm using TYPO3 4.5, but information for any version is appreciated.

Comment: In what context? Backend or Frontend?

Comment: Both are useful, but my first need is in Frontend.